# Slime: frame-source-location not implemented / is my sldb Backtrace output normal?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime

I'm debugging my (Common) Lisp code in Slime tied to clisp.

When the debugger generates the Backtrace it's my understanting that I can hit 'v' on a frame to take me to the source.

However, when I do this on the any frame I get:

```
frame-source-location not implemented
```

Is this expected, am I missing anything?

**Edit1**: In addition every single frame has "No Locals", is this to be expected too?

**Edit2**: In fact, the whole backtrace output is pretty unintelligible. I'm new to Lisp, so I wasn't initially sure if this was expected or not - but I'm attaching a screenshot, hopefully someone can confirm for me if this looks 'normal':

[image]

**Edit3** I'm guessing [this is related](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/browse_thread/thread/764f658c0eb2688f?hl=de)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting the question I have found [this link](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/browse_thread/thread/764f658c0eb2688f?hl=de) which seems to indicate the Slime and clisp integration is not quite working as it should be.

So, in the meantime I have installed Steel Bank Common Lisp (sbcl), as easy as (on Ubuntu/Debian)

```
sudo apt-get install sbcl
```

and configured Slime to use that instead of clisp:

Snippet of my .emacs file:

```
;;; Lisp (SLIME) interaction 
;;(setq inferior-lisp-program "clisp") 
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
```

This results in more pleasant debug output:

[image]

Comment: Steel Bank Common Lisp is "sbcl", not "sldb".